# How to get @tag in step definition from scenario ? - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara

How to get tags from scenario into step definition in Ruby?

```
**@TAGS**
Scenario: Showing information of the scenario
When I execute any scenario
```

Now my step definition is this:

```
And(/^When I execute any scenario$/) do |page|
  How to get tag = @TAGS in step definition..
end
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The purpose of tags is to choose which tests to (not) run, not to determine the behaviour of the test's steps.

Comment: If you find it helpful to define some behaviour *around* tests with specific tags e.g. different logging or "fail fast" then you could consider using tagged hooks: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks#tagged-hooks

Comment: @TomLord I need tags to perform some condition.

Comment: *"some condition"* -- What condition? That's what I was asking.

Comment: I suspect there is some easy way to express that logic without referencing a tag. E.g. `And(/^When I execute any scenario( with foobar)?$/) do |page|`

Comment: if condition, If it mock then I want to send different user and If it QA I want to send other user.   if we have @ mock tag on scenario, i can read the tag and decide which user I should send and same for @ QA tags

Comment: So as I guessed above, I would implement this as part of the step definition and not rely on the tag. Something like: `/^When I execute any scenario for (QA|mock) user$/`. You *could* also store the user in an instance variable, using a tagged hook, but defining "global" behaviour like this could potentially get very messy as your test suite grows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a direct solution, but hooks (Before, After, AfterStep, etc) can be set to run for specific tags, which allows you to set instance variables that are accessible in the scenario

```
Before('@my_tag') do  # will only run if the test has @my_tag tag
   @my_tag = true  # This instance variable will be accessible in the test
end
```

You could also use the fact that `Before` hooks get the scenario passed to them and use that to set an instance variable to the tag names

```
Before do |scenario|
  @tags = scenario.source_tag_names # @tags instance variable accessible in test
end
```